# Power Query: add 3 tables together, summing by column name

Tags: powerquery, m

I have three tables pulled into PowerQuery, each with the format headers=Countries, Rows=monthly_values (with column 1 being the month), eg:
Table1:

| Month | Ctry A | Ctry B | Ctry C | *etc.* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan-21 | 5 | 3 | 4 | *etc.* |
| Feb-21 | 4 | 5 | 7 | *etc.* |
| *etc.* | *etc.* | *etc.* | *etc.* | *etc.* |

Table2:

| Month | Ctry A | Ctry C | *etc.* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan-21 | -2 | -1 | *etc.* |
| Feb-21 | -1 | -4 | *etc.* |
| *etc.* | *etc.* | *etc.* | *etc.* |

Table3:

| Month | Ctry B | Ctry C | *etc.* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan-21 | -1 | -4 | *etc.* |
| Feb-21 | -2 | -1 | *etc.* |
| *etc.* | *etc.* | *etc.* | *etc.* |

What I would like to do is create a summation table, in which each country is summed across all three tables.
Each country is not necessarily in *all 3* tables, but where they do appear the column names match across the three tables. The rows (months) are equal/match across all three.

Desired output:

| Month | Ctry A | Ctry B | Ctry C | *etc.* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan-21 | 3 | 2 | -1 | *etc.* |
| Feb-21 | 3 | 3 | 2 | *etc.* |
| *etc.* | *etc.* | *etc.* | *etc.* | *etc.* |

Please any guidance on how to merge AND sum by the column header within PowerQuery / the M-syntax?

Answer (score 1):

You can append the three tables and then group by month.

It will probably be cleaner if you unpivot the country columns first, then append them together and group by Month and country name, and then re-pivot at the end if you want it back in the original shape.